# How to use a population of Queues

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to work out how to use the "Population of agents" radio button functionality in the Advanced section of the "Queue" block from the process library.

I am able to successfully select the "Population of agents" option and specify the number of queues to be in the population however I am then unable to direct agents to any of the queues in the population.  Ultimately, I need to send agents to specific queues in the collection (population) but I can't seem to work out how to do that.

The screenshot shows a bit more of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have the option to create a population of queues, there's no possible use for it since you can't add an agent to the queue without a flow (for insteance enter block)

In order to make a good population of queues, you need to create a population of agents called for instance QueueAgent

And in this queue agent you will have
enter->queue->exit

Then you can choose to what queue to send your agent to send it by using `queueAgents.get(index).enter.take(agent)` where index is the queue index to which your agent needs to be sent

the exit block will send your agent back to an enter block that will be connected to speacialtyProcesses

The only blocks in which it makes sense to create a population are the blocks that create agents such as source or enter blocks.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe, indeed that is a valid solution however I am intrigued as to why the option is there to create a population of queues if there is no valid reason to do so as they cannot be used anyhow...